# How to place an image on top of Bootstrap NavBar while keeping links clickable?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a Boostrap UI where the Desktop view (>= 992px) will have a logo just above the NavBar. I created the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4qd79699/

To place the logo where I want, I have the following CSS:

```
.navbar {
   top: -40px;
}
```

However, as you can see (you might need to expand result view to 992px) the logo is placed behind the NavBar (which makes sense). Now, how can I put the logo on top of the NavBar while being able to click the links?

I have tried adding the following:

```
.navbar {
   top: -40px;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Then it is displayed as I want but I can't click the links on the NavBar. For some reason I wasn't able to bring the logo "up" by switching its **z-index**.

Comment: Add a z-index on your logo as well (higher than the z-index of the navbar). Edit : http://jsfiddle.net/4qd79699/embedded/result/ (is that ok ?)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I actually tried setting z-index on the link and on the image without success. I imagine this has something to do with Bootstrap's container class. You can see my test here: http://jsfiddle.net/b85aLukf/.

Comment: `z-index` only works if the element has a position value that is something other than `static`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `position:absolute;` to the anchor holding your image and you can adjust the margin of your image accordingly after.

Here's a jsfiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/o49v85Lh/1/

Comment: Just wanted to add that wrapping the image on another div (as you did) makes all the difference. Because Bootstrap's container automatically expands to a certain width according to the current viewport. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for the image add a the style display:block; and remove the navbar top:-40px